# How can I discover which finger raised up from the screen first?

Tags: android, touch-event

In Android API level 7,when I use `ACTION_POINTER_UP`, how can I discover which finger raised up from the screen first?

There are only two touch points. I want to learn when a finger leaves the screen. This finger is the finger that first or last touched the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I discover which finger raised up from the screen first?

You can use `getActionIndex()` of `MotionEvent`

Comment: I'm sorry, my mobile notified me, Are you using 2 fingers only?

Comment: You can use `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_UP`.